# ATH: command not found

Tags: 20.04

Everytime I open my terminal in my Ubuntu 20.04 it shows the following message
`ATH: command not found`
.I remember changing the name of the ethernet device using the command `ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", NAME="eth0"`
.I don't even know if that has caused the problem or not.

Comment: You mean `PATH: command not found`? Check your .bashrc file: the problem is there.

Comment: No, it is showing  ATH: command not found

Comment: Unexpected. Still check your .bashrc. The error will be there.

Comment: RitwikMandal any update about @vanadium suggestion? if you modified .bashrc or .profile